# Ativar evento do botão ao dar enter em um edit

Tags: java, android

Criei uma tela de "cadastro" onde o usuário informa o nome/apelido e onde há um botão Continuar que vai para uma outra tela. Gostaria que essa nova tela fosse aberta quando o usuário apertasse a tecla Enter, porém não sei como fazer para a tecla Enter ter essa função.

Abaixo o código da tela inicial

```
public class CadastroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText edtNome;

Button btnContinuar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro);

    edtNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNome);

    btnContinuar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnContinuar);

    btnContinuar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent EnviarDados = new Intent(CadastroActivity.this, ResultadoActivity.class);

            String txtNome = edtNome.getText().toString();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            bundle.putString("nome", txtNome);

            EnviarDados.putExtras(bundle);

            startActivity(EnviarDados);

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A melhor prática para atingir isto que você quer é utilizar o evento `setOnEditorActionListener` do `EditText` como mostra [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17990096/5078248) ou [esta daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999131/android-edittext-key-return-goes-to-next-text).

Você vai precisar configurar o EditText no XML (caso não tenha feito) com o imeOptions correspondente a "próximo campo".

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext" />
```

Note que aqui definimos a propriedade `maxLines="1"`, que vai fazer com que o Android saiba que ao pressionar o Enter, deve-se avançar o campo. O `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` muda o desenho do botão "Enter" com uma seta, indicando para o usuário que ao clicar alí ele será levado para o próximo campo/tela/etc. Definir esta propriedade no XML também define a identificação do evento do Edit para que você possa executar a ação que deseja.

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
            callAnotherActivity();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Essa seria minha sugestão. Não seria capaz de ir tão profundo por dificuldades técnicas minhas mesmo, de não ter aprofundado em Android, mas pela teoria rumores sugerir isso. E detalhe importante: nessa resposta, implicitamente a ação de chamar a outra atividade fiquei encapsulada em um método. Assim, essa chamada pode ser aproveitada para ser usado pelo botão também

Comment: Sim, a título de aprendizado coloquei o listener explícito. Mas poderia ter feito `editText.setOnEditorActionListener(this)`, fazer a Activity estender a interface `OnEditorActionListener` e fazer uma verificação do campo a ser validado com `v.equals(editText)`.